# Struggling to match a string using preg_match_all()

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm searching for this:

```
<h1> sample string 123.456 - find me </h1>
```

Please note that its what's between the h1 tags that interests me. Please also not that the string is a variable that contains any combination of numbers, letters and/or characters. Therefore the following would also need to be found between the h1 tags using the same preg_match_all search:

```
<h1>there are no numbers this time</h1>
```

or

```
<h1>this one may be tricky ?!-.</h1>
```

I've now tried the following:

```
preg_match_all("/<h1>[\w\d\D\s]+?<\/h1>$/siU", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The script runs... but the `$matches` array contains no values when I `print_r()` it. It therefore looks like this 'Array ( [0] => Array ( ) ) '

Comment: `\s` stands for whitespaces not for alphanumeric characters. Even with the good class `"\z "` is able to make all patterns of the world to fail since there are no characters after the end of the string.

Comment: `^` is the start of the string. If your string only has `<h1>...` then correct the `h1` in the regex to have `<`. Also the `s` modifier is so the `.` matches multiple lines as well your regex isn't using `.`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. So if i edit the above to: "/^(<h1>)[\w]*<\/h1>/siU" ?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like `<h1>[a-zA-Z\d]+?<\/h1>`. https://regex101.com/r/lD5wQ3/1

Comment: If you want the content of `h1` tags have you considered a parser?

Comment: Does my revision help?

Comment: Is that your actual `preg_match_all` usage? Yes, revision helps. So you aren't validating some data format you just want all `h1`s right?

Comment: @chris85 - basically, yes. Anything within the 'h1' tags. I appreciate that my code is probably wrong and/or crude... i'm trying to learn...

Comment: I think the parser is best for you. If you are just trying to learn regexs with this though then I'd advise you to try your regexs out on a site that explains what each bit is doing. Something like regex101.com. Your `[\w\d\D\s]+?` is equivalent to `.+?`. Your `\d\D` says anything because you are allowing numbers and anything non-numbered. Also `\w` includes numbers.

Comment: Ok -- thanks for your help chris85 :).

Comment: If the parser works for you please be sure to accept the answer. If you have any questions or issues please post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a parser is probably your best option. Your question/comments are unclear and contradicting on what you are trying to identify.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html = '<h1>Hi</h1><h2>test</h2><strong>Test</strong><h1>More</h1>';
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$h1s = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1');
foreach ($h1s as $h1) {
    echo $h1->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

You then could use a regex on the `nodeValue` to confirm the value is as expected.

Output:

```
Hi
More
```

A regex for what your initial question was could be..

```
<h1>[a-zA-Z\d]+?<\/h1>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lD5wQ3/1

Comment: Hi - i never considered doing it this way. My question: is it a quicker method than preg_match_all? Similiarly, would this method be considered better practice? Say your searching 4,000 pages for arguments sake?

Comment: I think this a better and safer approach then using a regex. I haven't benchmarked so I can't say what the efficiency is/isnt.

Comment: Went with a parser in the end. For some reason... pre_match_all wasnt picking up the h1 tag.

Answer (score 0):

below gets all three of your strings:

```
<h1>\s?[a-z0-9\s?!.]*<\/h1>
```

Comment: Don't need `{1}`. `09` isn't a range. Also `\s` is requred OP only said alphanumeric.

Comment: then it should be written like: <h1>AlphanumericValueHere</h1>

Comment: I tried the above and got a similar result 'Array ( [0] => Array ( ) ) '. Any ideas?

Comment: @fsn there are white spaces, numbers, letters and potentially symbols in the string.

Comment: @GtDriver update the question with exact examples of what is expected. Your just going to get guesses if not.

Comment: OK -- please see my revision.

Comment: You have the digit ranges incorrect, `09` is a `0` and `9`. Also `!-.` is saying characters between a `!` and `.` are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what is the expected result? 
You can try this:

```
$input = '<h1> Alphanumeric value here </h1>';
preg_match_all("/^<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/su", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <h1> Alphanumeric value here </h1>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Alphanumeric value here 
        )

)
```

Comment: Hope he doesn't have more than 1 `h1` on the page. Your regex is greedy and will keep going. https://regex101.com/r/lD5wQ3/3

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("%^<h1>[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*</h1>$%siU", $input, $matches);
```

This will return text inside `<h1>` tags, so if you want tags included, simply do

`"<h1>".$result."</h1>"`